# Excel: Transform survery data

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I transform this survey data:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Have a hint : you could use FIND() to test for each letter A, B etc and then use IF() to populate the cell...

Answer (score 1):

**The below written VBA Code will help you to solve the problem, *but remember it works for a Column only*.**

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRg1 As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xRet As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select Input Range", "Transpose Data", xAddress, , , , , 8)
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "You Can't Select Multiple Columns", , "Transpose Data"
            Exit Sub
            End If

            Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Split to (Single Cell):", "Transpose Data", , , , , , 8)
            Set xRg1 = xRg1.Range("A1")

            If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
                xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                For Each xCell In xRg
                    xRet = Split(xCell.Value, ",")
                    xRg1.Worksheet.Range(xRg1.Offset(I, 0), xRg1.Offset(I + UBound(xRet, 1), 0)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xRet)
                    I = I + UBound(xRet, 1) + 1
                Next
                Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate

End Sub
```

[image]

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Almost there.  Can you take this the last step of matching the userid with the results, like in the question?

Comment: @fixer1234,, problem is user ID is in Row,,, !